# How to move Solution Explorer to the left in Visual Studio

Tags: windows-explorer, visual-studio-2022

The layout of the Solution Explorer section on my Visual Studio 2022 is on the right, is there a way to move it to the left? I need the Explorer on the left so it looks like the solution explorer for all the Jetbrains IDEs, which have their project file browser on the left?
[image]

Comment: Yes; Just drag and drop and a docking mechanic will be shown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need the Explorer on the left so it looks like the solution explorer for all the Jetbrains IDEs, which have their project file browser on the left?

Just drag and drop onto the mechanic and dock the solution explorer window to the left side of the window.

You must drop the panel onto the fastener, in the position you wish it to be docked (in the case, the rectangle on the left of the fastener, highlighted with a red circle).

[image]

Comment: And an article on the same https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: it floats on the left, but does not dock, though it drags but does not show me a preview for docking when i ove it around the left section

Comment: Grab it and drop it onto the left-most rectangle on the fastener. "Tool windows can be fastened to one side of a frame in the IDE or within the editing frame. A guide diamond appears when you drag a tool window to another location to help you to easily redock the window." Have a look at the article I linked above.

Comment: @spikey_richie, thatis the information the answer did not include and is needed for a succesful dock to the left, Thanks

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated the answer to make it clearer. Hope that's cool with you.

Comment: I figured it was self-apparent that the docking icon appear when you dragged the window.

Answer (score 10):

First, you `Drag` the *Solution Explorer*, then the guide diamond will appear.

The guide diamond:

[image: The guide diamond]

After that, you move the cursor to the left most square in the guide then `Drop` the panel.

Document here: [Customize window layouts in Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) - [Dock Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#dock-windows).

Comment: thanks mate +1 for u

Comment: Thanks, MS' own explanation is garbage and assumes you already know to do this even if it's been years since your last VS version upgrade,

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with Visual Studio 1.85 and you can click with right button on the explorer area and choose which side you want to move the explorer like the image.

[image: right click to change explorer position]